# CompanionDeviceManager 'onDeviceFound' Callback Function Not Being Called if searched by uuid

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to use `CompanionDeviceManager` to pair BLE devices by specific UUID list without success.
using `deviceFilterBuilder.setNamePattern(Pattern.compile(DEVICE_NAME))` works.
another question is how can i add multiple uuids to ScanFilter.

```
   deviceManager = currentActivity.getSystemService(CompanionDeviceManager.class);

    BluetoothLeDeviceFilter.Builder deviceFilterBuilder = new BluetoothLeDeviceFilter.Builder();

    ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString(uuidString)).build();

   deviceFilterBuilder.setScanFilter(filter);
    deviceFilter = deviceFilterBuilder.build();

    pairingRequest = new AssociationRequest.Builder()
            .addDeviceFilter(deviceFilter)
            .build();

    deviceManager.associate(pairingRequest,
            new CompanionDeviceManager.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onDeviceFound(IntentSender chooserLauncher) {
                    try {

                        currentActivity.startIntentSenderForResult(chooserLauncher,
                                SELECT_DEVICE_REQUEST_CODE, null, 0, 0, 0);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.d("test", "error");

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(CharSequence charSequence) {
                    Log.d("test", "error");
                }
            },
            null);
```

Comment: Adding multile UUIDs to scan for can be done by creating a BluetoothLeDeviceFilter for each service UUID, and adding them to the association request via AssociationRequest.Builder().addDeviceFilter().
However, I still see the same issue you do, in that trying to filter by UUIDs results in no devices being found by CDM, vs. setting a name pattern, which does work. <sigh, lament>

Comment: Thanks! so you are using the pattern ?

Comment: Yes. The following works, but setting a scan filter (based on service UUID) on the device filter doesn't seem to, while setting a name pattern does.

deviceFilter1 = new BluetoothLeDeviceFilter.Builder()
  .setNamePattern(Pattern.compile("test_name_1"))
  .build();

deviceFilter2 = new BluetoothLeDeviceFilter.Builder()
  .setNamePattern(Pattern.compile("test_name_2"))
  .build();

pairingRequest = new AssociationRequest.Builder()
  .addDeviceFilter(deviceFilter1)
  .addDeviceFilter(deviceFilter2)
  .setSingleDevice(false)
  .build();

Comment: I'm still trying to find a way, though. Using a name pattern is not optimal for what I need to do.

Comment: I'm also seeing that the onDeviceFound() callback is only called once, even if it finds multiple devices, even if I turn on a new device after the onDeviceFound() callback had been called.

Comment: thanks for the information, i am also trying to debug the native code to try to understand

Comment: @JohnMichaelZorko opened an issue in google issue tracker, https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/167925047

Comment: No answer here nor in Google's issue tracker...