# CompanionDeviceManager does not find any devices when filtering for service UUID on my Sony Xperia XZ2 Compact

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, sony

Building a small app using `CompanionDeviceManager` following the documentation from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/companion-device-pairing .

Calling `CompanionDeviceManager.associate(...)` with an `BluetoothDeviceFilter` Filter by battery service `.addServiceUuid(ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString("0000180F-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")), null)` no device is shown at all despite there is a least one nearby.
My test device is an Sony Xperia XZ2 Compact (H8324, Android 10, Build 52.1.A.3.49).

Calling `CompanionDeviceManager.associate(...)` with an empty (without any UUID set) `BluetoothDeviceFilter` i see all the devices around.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried using just the 16-bit UUID of the Battery Service? It is "0x180F"

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan tried it like this. No luck so far.

```lang-kotlin
 val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
        buffer.putShort(0x180F);
        val array =  buffer.array();
        val filter = BluetoothLeDeviceFilter.Builder()
   .setScanFilter(ScanFilter.Builder().setManufacturerData(ScanRecord.DATA_TYPE_SERVICE_UUIDS_16_BIT_COMPLETE, array).build())
            .build()
        val pairingRequest = AssociationRequest.Builder()
            .addDeviceFilter(filter)
            .build()

Comment: Are you sure there is a device around that advertises a battery service?

Comment: Thanks for coming back. Without the `ScanFilter` i get all the devices nearby including the device with battery service. The resulting `ScanResult`object contains the battery service uuid also. Guess i need another test device.

Comment: I took another look at the documentation and tried to come up with a working version. I realized I was just producing the same code you already used... Sorry, I'm at the end of my wisdom :(

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's more effort i was hoping for! Nice to have my approach validated. For now, i have two possible explanations: there is a bug in my test device and the other is, there is some problem in the way the Bluetooth device does its advertising. Will do some testing on other android devices as soon as i get access. Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63765131/companiondevicemanager-ondevicefound-callback-function-not-being-called-if-sea

Comment: Still no answer? I have the very same problem... everything works until I add the service UUID filter.

Comment: @Baltasarq not yet. What Device do you test on?

Comment: My device is a Blackview 7200 with Android 12. I guess the only solution would be to accept any device and check the service later...

Comment: That's what i'm doing for now. Need a way to help my users to select only valid ble devices.

Comment: Had a chance to test with a Google Pixel 6 running Android 14: Filtering by service UUID worked. No Problem at all.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77294327/androids-companiondevicemanager-associate-fails-to-find-any-device-when-filte