# Android's CompanionDeviceManager associate() fails to find any device when filtering by service

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using [Google Android's CompanionDeviceManager API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/companion-device-pairing) in order to find **Bluetooth LE** nearby devices able to measure Heart Rate.

```java
    final BluetoothLeDeviceFilter DEVICE_FILTER =
                    new BluetoothLeDeviceFilter.Builder()
                        .setScanFilter( new ScanFilter.Builder()
                        /*    .setServiceUuid(
                                    ParcelUuid.fromString( "0000180D-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" )
                        */
                            .build() ).build();

    final AssociationRequest PAIRING_REQ = new AssociationRequest.Builder()
                    .addDeviceFilter( DEVICE_FILTER )
                    .setSingleDevice( false )
                    .build();

    final CompanionDeviceManager DEV_MANAGER =
                    (CompanionDeviceManager) getSystemService(
                                        Context.COMPANION_DEVICE_SERVICE );

    DEV_MANAGER.associate( PAIRING_REQ, new CompanionDeviceManager.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onDeviceFound(@NonNull IntentSender chooserLauncher)
            {            
                try {
                    startIntentSenderForResult( chooserLauncher, RCQ_SELECT_DEVICE,
                                            null, 0, 0, 0 );
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.e( LOG_TAG, "onAssociationPending: failed to send intent" );
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(CharSequence errorMessage)
            {
                Log.e( LOG_TAG, "[FAIL] " + errorMessage );
            }
        }, null );
```

Please note the commented lines at the beginning of the source code. I know this code works because, it its current state, it shows a dialog with all **Bluetooth LE** devices nearby, including the ones I'm interested in.

The problem comes when I remove the comment marks above, therefore filtering by the heart rate service. In my own device with Android 12, nothing appears on screen, not even a dialog with an empty device list. I've even tried to leave it there for hours, but nothing changes.

My expectations are:

- There should be a dialog or at least a message showing that the device is scanning.
- That dialog should have a time out, and then report that no device was found with the current filter.

It is possible I am making some mistake invoking the API, though. Any ideas? Any help will be truly appreciated.

FWIW, I'm aware of [this question with no answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63765131/companiondevicemanager-ondevicefound-callback-function-not-being-called-if-sea).